# Webpage located in an Apache IE but not with Chrome, and doesn't work in other PC

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, apache-http-server, internet-explorer-9, flash-player

A friend developed a webpage which has some tables to show information. We run it on a native Apache on two PCs. 
The first one has installed IE9 with Adobe Flash Player 10.3.181.26 and Chrome with Adobe Flash Player 10.3.183.7. The tables show the information on IE but not on Chrome.

When we see the webpage in the second PC in IE looks the same way as the Chrome picture. The PC had installed IE9 with Adobe Flash Player 10.3.183.7 but we uninstalled it and installed Adobe Flash Player 10.3.181.26 thinking that was the problem. That didn't fix it.

Then we resetted the advanced configuration of IE and didn't work either. We copied the whole folder of the webpage that was on the first PC Apache folder to the second PC Apache folder and didn't work.

Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Can you post the page itself?

Answer (score 0):

check your spelling, including capitalization. I would assume that IE would not care about case sensitivity, but chrome would. This is the best guess I can provide you with since I dont know enough details.